# android add marker to google maps

Tags: android, android-intent, maps, marker

This is not duplicate..I have tried all possible code to add marker on my map which is loading on intent but its not working..Please suggest any other way.. Below is my code. Do we need to add any dependencies? May be Im missing out on something. Can you please help with full code for marker?

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:13.01083,77.579510"));
            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Launch Map");
            startActivity(chooser);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer and its working fine

```
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:" + eslat  + "," + eslon + "?q=" + eslat  + "," + eslon + ")"));
```